# Why does adding a user to a group increase the size of this centos:latest Docker image to 22.7GB?

Tags: docker

I have pulled up the `centos:latest` Docker image which has an initial size of around 250 MB. After adding the lines below to create a group and add a user to the group the size of the docker image is ballooning to 22.7 GB.

I am not able to figure out why size is getting increased so much. Any ideas?

Here is the complete docker file:

```
FROM centos:latest

# Add x_user user
ARG user=x_user
ARG group=lxs_x_user
ARG uid=11111
ARG gid=22222

# Set environment variables
ENV HOME_DIR=/home/"$user"
ENV BASHRC_PATH=/home/"$user"/.bashrc
ENV SHELL=/bin/bash

# Create group 
RUN groupadd --gid "$gid" --system "$group"

# Create user and add to the group
RUN useradd  -G "$group" "$user" \
    --uid "$uid" \
    --gid "$gid" \
    --home-dir "$HOME_DIR"
```

Comment: Kindly copy the full dockerfile here. Usually docker image creation works on layers. every instruction is created as a layer. you may combine create group to the subsequent instruction. apart from this, please copy the dockerfile to inspect.

Comment: Added complete docker file

Comment: 22.7 GB? Are you sure? How did you get this figure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the `--no-log-init` flag resolved the problem.

```
RUN useradd  -G "$group" "$user" \
    --uid "$uid" \
    --gid "$gid" \
    --home-dir "$HOME_DIR" \
    --no-log-init
```

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5419

Comment: From the github issue: "The underlying issue is that a large sparse file is created (approximately 32 GB), but it's not exactly a Docker bug."

Comment: What does addgroup increase the size?